# Use the value of a variable in the mode of apply-templates

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I want to apply a template with a mode that depends on a variable value.

```
<xsl:variable name="mode" select="@attribute"/>
<xsl:apply-templates mode="{$mode}"/>
```

I get the error that the stylesheet cannot be compiled. The value of mode should be a QName, but it is "{$mode}".

Is there a possibilty to use modes dependent on variables?

Comment: What you want to do is syntactically illegal, but it is *possible* in XSLT 1.0 to achieve the same effect, using the "template reference" principle that is the foundation for the FXSL library.

Comment: Thank you for this idea! I tried to understand it, but I am new at XSLT and don't have much experience with functional programming. For the described case, it is "over-engineered". Maybe, I can use it some times, when I have more experience with it.

Comment: maria90, It is enough to know that such technique exists -- then to use it whenever necessary.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The only option you have to use a certain mode based on an expression is to use

```
<xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="@attribute = 'foo'">
      <xsl:apply-templates mode="bar"/>
   </xsl:when>
   <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
   </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

or the same with an `xsl:if`. The `mode` attribute value itself needs to be a `QName` in XSLT 1.0 respectively in XSLT 2.0 allows a `QName` or special tokens like `#current` or `#default`'. But you can't compute a `mode` value at run-time.

Comment: This was my first idea to solve the problem. I wanted to avoid testing specific values of the variable. Nevertheless, I will use this way because FXSL is a bit to heavy for me.

Answer (score 5):

*mode* is not a valid candidate for Attribute Value Templates (AVT). You simply can't do this.

From the [XSLT 2.0 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#attribute-value-templates):

> [Definition: In an attribute that is designated as an attribute value
>   template, such as an attribute of a literal result element, an
>   expression can be used by surrounding the expression with curly
>   brackets ({})].

*mode* is not designated as AVT in the spec, so ou can't do this.

Answer (score 2):

> I get the error that the stylesheet cannot be compiled. The value of
>   mode should be a QName, but it is "{$mode}".
>
> Is there a possibilty to use modes dependent on variables?

No, this is not supported in any XSLT version -- 1.0, 2.0 or 3.0.

As you are trying in effect to emulate Higher Order Functions (HOF), you may use the underlying principle of **[FXSL](http://fxsl.sf.net)** to do this in XSLT 1.0.

FXSL 1.x is a library of templates written in pure XSLT 1.0 that supports/emulates HOF.

**Here is a complete solution based on these principles**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:f="http://fxsl.sf.net" exclude-result-prefixes="f">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

   <f:inc/>
   <f:double/>

 <xsl:variable name="vModeInc" select="document('')/*/f:inc[1]"/>
 <xsl:variable name="vModeDouble" select="document('')/*/f:double[1]"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <nums>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$vModeInc">
      <xsl:with-param name="pNodes" select="node()"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </nums>
==============
  <nums>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$vModeDouble">
      <xsl:with-param name="pNodes" select="node()"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </nums>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="f:inc">
   <xsl:param name="pNodes"/>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="$pNodes" mode="incr"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="f:double">
   <xsl:param name="pNodes"/>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="$pNodes" mode="double"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="num" mode="incr">
  <num><xsl:value-of select=".+1"/></num>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="num" mode="double">
  <num><xsl:value-of select=".*2"/></num>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document:**

```
<nums>
  <num>01</num>
  <num>02</num>
  <num>03</num>
  <num>04</num>
  <num>05</num>
  <num>06</num>
  <num>07</num>
  <num>08</num>
  <num>09</num>
  <num>10</num>
</nums>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced** -- the `nums/num` elements processed in one (each) of the two modes available, depending on the variable specified -- `$vModeInc` (1 added to each value) or `$vModeDouble` (each value is multiplied by two):

```
<nums>
   <num>2</num>
   <num>3</num>
   <num>4</num>
   <num>5</num>
   <num>6</num>
   <num>7</num>
   <num>8</num>
   <num>9</num>
   <num>10</num>
   <num>11</num>
</nums>
==============
  <nums>
   <num>2</num>
   <num>4</num>
   <num>6</num>
   <num>8</num>
   <num>10</num>
   <num>12</num>
   <num>14</num>
   <num>16</num>
   <num>18</num>
   <num>20</num>
</nums>
```

Comment: +1 That's clever. I have not kept up on FXSL, but have wished I had time to do so. :-) For anybody else who's reading, it's worth your time to trace through the XSLT above and see what it's doing.

Comment: @LarsH, Thanks, just read the Extreme Markup Languages paper on FXSL 2 -- it doesn't take too much time. :)

Comment: can you give a link to that paper? I googled and found this: http://fxsl.sourceforge.net/ which has a links to 2 papers, both of which are broken. Oh, is this it? http://conferences.idealliance.org/extreme/html/2006/Novatchev01/EML2006Novatchev01.html

Comment: @LarsH: This one isn't broken (from my SO profile): http://conferences.idealliance.org/extreme/html/2006/Novatchev01/EML2006Novatchev01.html